# Taking the derivative of a vector and non-vector that represent the same thing?

Tags: calculus

In a cylindrical coordinate system, the following formula is used derived for theta acceleration by taking the derivative of the position function $r=r \vec{u_r}$, ($\vec{u_r}$ is a unit vector)

$a_\theta = r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}$

My question is as follows, confusion about derivatives.

We can also note that in circular motion, the radial component is always constant and that $s=r\theta$. (semicircle formula) Taking the derivative of this twice, we can get $a_r=\ddot{s}=r \ddot{\theta}$

Is this valid to say? $s$ has no direction, and we didn't take it into account.  All we took into account was the length of the semicircle, which isn't a vector.

Can we do things like this in calculus? Or must we always take vectors into account too?  If we have to take vectors into account, how an we define the vector for $s$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must be careful to recall that the unit vectors are functions of $\theta$ and that $\theta$ is a function of time.  The position vector is $r(t)\hat r(\theta(t))$.  Upon differentiating once, we get $$v(t)\hat v(t)=r'(t)\hat r(\theta(t))+r(t)\theta'(t)\hat \theta(\theta(t))$$Then, a second derivative reveals $$a(t)\hat a(t)=r''(t)\hat r(\theta(t))+2r'(t)\theta'(t)\hat \theta(\theta(t))+r(t)[\theta''(t)\hat \theta(\theta(t))-[\theta'(t)]^2\hat r(\theta(t))]$$$$=\hat r(\theta(t))[r''(t)-r(t)[\theta''(t)]^2]+\hat \theta(\theta(t))[2r'(t)\theta'(t)+r(t)\theta''(t)]$$ For the special case for which $r(t)$ is constant, then the acceleration is $$=-\hat r(\theta(t))[r(t)\theta''(t)]^2]+\hat \theta(\theta(t))[r(t)\theta''(t)]$$

Comment: What about if we only care about the magnitude of the acceleration.  Is it legal to note that the length of an arc $s = r \theta$ then differentiate this twice with constant r?  We then get $a_\theta = r \ddot{\theta}$

Comment: The magnitude of the acceleration will be the square root of the sum of the squares of the radial and angular components.